# jsf table : display cell borders when cell is empty

Tags: html, jsf, datatable, space

In my jsf pages i have table with column as such where i am checking if value is empty than put a space in cell.

```
<h:column >
        <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText
                       value="File" style="color:red;"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{logs.FILE == null ? ' ' : logs.FILE}"/>
</h:column>
```

Html displayed

```
<td class="sc5"> </td>
```

In Firefox as well as IE, when a cell in table is empty, no cell borders are drawn.
but chrome does draw border.
So how can i make firefox and IE to draw borders for empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try outputting a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` instead of a `' '` in a blank cell.

```
<h:outputText value="#{logs.FILE == null ? '&nbsp;' : logs.FILE}" escape="false" />
```